# StopPropagation for Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

For the DataTable, there is a row click select function and in one cell, there are action buttons.

Comp 1:

```
<aura:component >
    ..
    <tr class="{! 'file-list-row ' + (file.checked?'slds-is-selected':'')}" onclick="{!c.toggleRowSelect}" data-file-id="{!file.id}">

         <td>
               <c:Actions file="{!file}" objectName="cg__S3Object__c" ></c:Actions>
         </td>
    </tr>
    ..
</aura:component>
```

I want to stop propogation for action buttons on click. And according to documantation I have tried to:

Comp 2 (Actions):

```
<aura:component controller="FileListController">

..
<aura:registerEvent name="sampleComponentEvent" type="COMPONENT"/>
<aura:handler name="sampleComponentEvent" event="COMPONENT" action="{!c.handleSampleEvent}"/>

    ..
</aura:component>
```

and the controller should be:

```
handleBubbling: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_bubbling.htm

However I get this error message over and over again, no matter what I try:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aura:registeretevent name = "samplecompnent"  type ="c:eventname" 
 you have not specified  type in register event

Comment: I have tried this also, `type ="c:copmEvent"` but error message is same...

Comment: I just want to prevent event propagation from component to container component...

Comment: Did you specified event ="c:eventname" in handler also

Comment: Can you post what is event name and event here

Comment: Yes, I have also used this eventname for handler... 
`<aura:registerEvent name="sampleComponentEvent" type="c:compEvent"/>
<aura:handler name="sampleComponentEvent" event="c:compEvent" action="{!c.handleSampleEvent}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is NOT regular way, but after two hour of time lose, it works...

```
<aura:component >
    <div onclick="{!c.mainDivClik}">

        ..

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

On the controller:

```
mainDivClik: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: We use a similar approach in Salesforce1. Would like to see a native / aura way as well